# Quick Books accounting software

Tags: display

Using a square 17" lcd monitor, and setting the Monitor to display text in larger font than default, some of the pages in QB have the bottom 2 or 3 lines chopped off.

QB support has no ideas for a different/larger monitor that would solve the problem for those of us with 50 something eyes.  Seems like everyone is going to the widescreen format, but when we tried one on the QB stuff, it spreads out the page to the point that it is deformed...too wide.

Does anybody make a new square screen monitor in 19, 20, or bigger that would solve this issue.  we can't be the only ones experiencing this.

Answer (score 1):

Two answers in one,

- install PowerStrip and force your square display to use non-standart, widescreen resolution; 1440x900 height scaled? 1360x768? (was quite fine on my 17 4:3 crt..). Then, compensate the font deformation by using height-compact fonts (I used Monaco, but turned to Dejavu).
- there are no more cheap 4:3 panels; latest seen are HP's professional workstations with displays costing around 3 times more than those widescreen stuff.